# Android Mapview: Hide/Toggle markers?

Tags: android, android-maps, android-mapview

I currently have an Android Mapview that displays a very basic subclass of OverlayItem with some custom properties:

```
    public class StreetLocation extends OverlayItem{
    public int id;
    public float latitude, longitude;
    public float distance;
    boolean isHouse = false;
    boolean hasSnacks = false;

... and so on, with a bunch of getters/setters
}
```

These are retrieved from a database, via building a co-ordinate span region (based on the user's view of the map) with no problems at all.

Now I have added a few simple `Button`'s on my UI which I wish to use to toggle the display of markers with `isHouse` and / or `hasSnacks`. Currently the only way I can think of doing this is by completely clearing the MapView of *all* markers, then adding only the ones I want back on to the MapView, by filtering the array of `StreetLocation`'s I get back from my database for the users view.

My issue with this is that this seems like a lot of work - is there any other way to simply hide or toggle the visual representation of the marker without clearing the entire map, since all markers are retrieved initially regardless of properties?

My apologies if this was a bit long, and I'll be glad to explain more / post code if required.